# How to reset the box

Tags: vb6

Using masked box in the form

```
masked1.mask = ##:##
```

In form load, masked1 display as `__:__`

Once user enter the values like 08:00 then reset means it should display again like this `__:__`

How to do this?

Comment: How many times do I need to say that you don't need to put "Need vb6 code help"? It's already implied by asking a question with the [vb6] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear a MaskEditBox you set the **Text** property to an empty string, however when the **PromptInclude** property is True you'll get an error. I would suggest writing a Sub method that you can call when you want to clear it.

```
Private Sub ClearMaskedEditBox(ByVal vMaskEditBox As MaskEdBox)
Dim strMask As String

    strMask = vMaskEditBox.Mask  'save the current mask
    vMaskEditBox.Mask = ""       'clear the control's mask
    vMaskEditBox.Text = ""       'clear the text
    vMaskEditBox.Mask = strMask  'reset the mask

End Sub
```

To use you call the Sub with the MaskEditBox control you want to clear.

```
Call ClearMaskedEditBox(masked1)
```